# Pandas DataFrame to Bootstrap Table

Tags: javascript, python, json

I have successfully passed a DataFrame table to html by converting it to a Json Object. Here is what the Json object looks like.

```
accrued_income:{1501545600000: 236368.08, 1501632000000: 239957.09, Pct_Change: 1.5183987618}
nav:{1501545600000: 24.37265947, 1501632000000: 24.43271182, Pct_Change: 0.2463922744}
outstanding_shares_par:{1501545600000: 865725.234, 1501632000000: 865725.234, Pct_Change: 0}
security_value:{1501545600000: 19863626.03, 1501632000000: 19938086.06, Pct_Change: 0.3748561813}
shareholder_equity:{1501545600000: 21100026.32, 1501632000000: 21152015.16, Pct_Change: 0.2463922993}
total_assets:{1501545600000: 21198382.3, 1501632000000: 21250293, Pct_Change: 0.2448804785}
```

Now I want to display this on a `Bootstrap Table.` There are three columns: `1501545600000`, `1501632000000`, and 'Pct_Change'. The first two columns basically are DateTime converted into a unix format. Furthermore, I want the the `keys` to be row labels. Essentially I want a table that looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, I understand you've parsed the DataFrame to JSON with the dataframe `to_json()` method? [https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html]. And now you're attempting to turn that into a regular table (and style it with bootstrap?)

Comment: That is correct

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Unless you're doing something with JSON that you cannot perform with pandas, you can directly parse your DataFrame from pandas into an HTML table and assign the appropriate CSS classes while doing it.

```
# Creates the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(myData)

# Parses the dataframe into an HTML element with 3 Bootstrap classes assigned.
html = df.to_html(classes=["table-bordered", "table-striped", "table-hover"])
```

More info about the `to_html()` method: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html

Comment: Okay, how would I modify individual elements?

Comment: What do you mean modify individual elements. Can you provide an example of what you would want to do?

Comment: `to_html()` is the last step of the process. If you require different field/column names or other ways of categorizing and grouping the data then you should make these changes within pandas' domain

Comment: Put the classes as `classes=["table table-bordered table-striped table-hover"]` instead of comma separated. I had issues with Bootstrap 3.4.1.

Answer (score -1):

```
#name of the table class

classes = 'table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-sm'

#table type inside the classes

html_table = df.to_html(classes=classes)
```